# Can RxJS/Most Observable be integrated?

Tags: gun

I would like to be able to use an Observables library of sorts to integrate with other parts of my system.

It looks like having Observables streams would work nicely with `gun`. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a guy named @ctrlplusb ;) made an extension for this: https://github.com/ctrlplusb/gun-most . Nice one!

Answer (score 2):

Apart from using a library integration, another solution is to build your own Observables from Gun instances. See this codesandbox for example: https://codesandbox.io/s/pYj4OM8m1

```
const user$ = name => // returns a new observable
  Observable.create(o => 
    gun.get(name).on(v => {
      o.next(v); // passes any new values to the observers
      console.log(v);
    }),
  );

// now you can do rx stuff on the stream of values
user$('something'))
      .map(({ name }) => ({ name: name.toUpperCase() }))
      .filter(({ name }) => name.length > 0)
```